# Static files such as CSS and images are not loading in the Laravel project on an EC2 instance server

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, amazon-ec2, server

This is my folder structure. I have uploaded a Laravel project on an EC2 instance. The static files such as CSS and images are not loading. I got 404 error in that static files location.but files are in that location.

```
/project
       /app
       /bootstrap
       /public
          /frontend
             /common
               /css
                 main.css
                 main-rtl.css
          index.php
```

this is nginx setup.Is there anything to add in nginx setup.

```
server {
        listen   80;
        root /home/ubuntu/websites/farmersdirect.lk/public_html/public;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        server_name dev.farmersdirect.lk test.ersdirect.lk;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/websites/farmersdirect.lk/logs/error.log;
   
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

    #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload';
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    #add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';";
        
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~* /(?:uploads|files|wp-content|wp-includes|akismet)/.*.php$ {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

What is the issue with the CSS and images not loading?

Comment: Have you tried by removing `proxy_pass` directive under the `location /` block? If it doesn't work, try to remove all proxy directives if your application doesnn't require proxying to another server.

Comment: Not worked still I removed